# Google Maps custom marker's icon doesn't load

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, google-maps-markers, google-geocoding-api

I tried the solutions from other answers in StackOverflow, but I got no result.

When loading the page, the icons of custom markers doesn't load.

The icon is in the same directory.
Here is the code: [Pastebin_link](http://pastebin.com/g2Ye57Ck)

Please help me.

Thank you!

Comment: At last it works! http://pastebin.com/dRMZqF24

Comment: I've noticed you put all the content of your question and self-answer into pastebin - you should put the relevant code directly in the Q&A itself - Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the image file in the Row you initialize at row 71, not where you are placing it now.

Comment: It just changes the setting icon to custom, but hospital icons don't show up.